# Cannot reference string-type key in associative array

Tags: javascript, associative-array

I have a hashtable in Javascript that has the below form when inspected.

```
Object {"securiguard_Org
": "line 2
", "securiguard_Exp
": "line 4
", "securiguard_Time
": "line 6
", "securiguard_Other
": "line 8"
, property: "value"}
```

**companyDataHashTable["property"] returns "value".
companyDataHashTable["securiguard_Org"] returns 'undefined'**

**What should I be doing to be able to return "line 2" for property "securiguard_Org"?**  Is there a way to remove those double quotes for all the keys because that seems to be the issue.

Other info: the securiguard property/values were added using json $.get reading a text file while the "property: "value"" I added myself for testing.

Comment: in the object it is written `"securiguard_Time "` ... you missed the " " space character

Comment: You obviously have line breaks.

Comment: In JavaScript, they are not called "hashtables" or "associative arrays"; they are called "objects".

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand the issue now. Yes, I read the file line by line -- splitting it by newline char \n. One thing I would like to know is how did you guys know there was a \n char after the property name? Because of the quotes surrounding the securiguard properties as opposed to my test "property"?

Answer (score 0):

It's really odd you have new line in indexes you should correct the way you generate it. Any way one of following should return the value:

```
companyDataHashTable["securiguard_Org\n"];

companyDataHashTable["securiguard_Org\r\n"];

companyDataHashTable["securiguard_Org "];

companyDataHashTable["securiguard_Org \n"];

companyDataHashTable["securiguard_Org \r\n"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I understand the issue now.  Yes, I read the file line by line -- splitting it by newline char \n.  One thing I would like to know is how did you guys know there was a \n char after the property name?  Because of the quotes surrounding the securiguard properties as opposed to my test "property"?